# In vue3 , TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '__vInternal' in true

Tags: vue.js

When I use the packaged modal component, the above error occurs

here is my code

define

```js
<template>
    <Modal
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :mask-closable="false"
    class="popEvent"
     >
     <slot></slot>
     <template v-slot:footer>
      <slot name="footer" ></slot>
     </template>
     <template v-slot:header>
        <slot name="header" ></slot>
     </template>
    </Modal>
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref} from 'vue';
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'DHCCModal',
  inheritAttrs: false,
  setup(props, cex){
    onMounted(()=>{
      // setLeft(menuStatus)
    });
    return {
      // popEvent
    };
  }
});

</script>
```

use

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <DHCCModal v-bind="true">
      <div>
        jack
      </div>
    </DHCCModal>        
  </div>
</template>
```

An error occurred

typeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '__vInternal' in true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering occurs because you're trying to bind a boolean value (true) to the v-bind directive on the DHCCModal component. The v-bind directive expects an object, not a boolean. update use like it fix  the issue you are facing need more clearance for what you trying to do then will help.

```
 <DHCCModal>
  <template #default>
    <div>
      jack
    </div>
  </template>
</DHCCModal>
```